# Low read latency SSD

Tags: ssd, hard-drive

What's the most cost effective low latency (when reading) SSD?

My application involves DB searching, so write performance isn't a concern.  64GB is sufficient

I've looked at Fusion IO ioXtreme, intel X25-E and intel X25-M.  Was surprised to see that, on paper, the X25-M seems to have the lowest read latency of 64 microseconds.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered disk backed RAM?  64G of RAM isn't that expensive, and the latency and bandwidth is pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the FusionIO cards have a read latency of 26µs.

Comment: I think that's the ioDrive, which costs super big money.  Too much for me.

Comment: You didn't mention a budget yet mention FusionIO - you're hard to please.

Comment: That's why I simply told you it was too much for me - you're touchy.

Answer (score 1):

X25-E will offer enterprise level quality, and has decent read latency of around 75 microseconds. Certain PCI-E offerings will offer smaller latency, but most of them are made to support higher capacities and to have higher sequential speed, so the price will be much higher.

Currently, you can buy several X25-M 80GB drives for the price of one X25-E 64GB drive and RAID them up for redundancy and performance benefits.

Comment: So it sounds like I might be missing "enterprise level quality".  Could you explain what what you mean?  I'm biggest priority is read latency.

Comment: X25-M is the desktop line of Intel's SSDs, made from MLC flash memory which is slightly less durable to extensive writes, as opposed to X25-E which uses SLC flash memory.

Comment: Good point, they wear out!